# equations which satisfy argument in complex numbers-help

Tags: complex-numbers

Please help

use an argand diagram to find, in the form a+bi, the complex numbers which satisfy the following pairs of equations.
arg(z+1)=1/4π,arg(z-3)=3/4π

thanks

Comment: I tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=a+bi$. For $\arg (z+1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ we have

$\large \frac{b}{a+1} = \tan \frac{\pi}{4}=1$

For $\arg (z-3)=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ we have

$\large \frac{b}{a-3} = \tan \frac{3\pi}{4}=-1$

Thus we have

$a+1=b$

$3-a=b$

Solving this pair of simultaneous equations results in $a=1$ and $b=2$

Thus $z=1+2i$

Answer (score 1):

> use an argand diagram

Here is a geometric solution represented in the [Argand Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane), using complex addition and subtraction. The complex $z=1+2i$ is at the intersection of the two red lines as shown in the diagram below. These red lines are paralel to the line $y=x$ and $y=-x$, where $x$ represents the real part and $y$ the imaginary part of a generic complex $z=x+iy$.

[image]